# In Sublime Text, why aren't files in sidebar being loaded/shown?

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3

When I switch projects only the root folder of that project shows up on the sidebar. The files inside don't come up, even if I hit 'Refresh Folders'.

If I close & re-open Sublime Text, the folders load immediately.

Notes: All of these projects are using files on Network drives. One project per client. I suspect this is somehow causing it.

I'm using Windows 7 64-bit.

This has happened on every version of Sublime I've tried installing. I have Sublime Text 3 (build 3059) right now.

Comment: I am receiving this error in the console: ReadDirectoryChangesW fails error code 50

Answer (score 1):

This appears similar to [the issue described here](http://twigstechtips.blogspot.com/2013/02/sublime-text-2-subfolders-not-appearing.html):

> If you've got issues opening 2nd level directories, remedy this by
>   going to:
>
> Preferences > Settings - User
>
> Add in this line "ignore_inodes": true
>
> Save and restart ST2. The subfolders SHOULD show up. If not, remove
>   the folder from your project and add them again.
>
> Note: This hidden setting was added to build 2197 (11th of May, 2012)
>   for Windows only.